# Creating a line that follows the cursor with a set length

Tags: vb.net, vector, cursor, angle

I'm trying to make a line with a fixed x1/y1, and when the user moves the cursor, its other end goes to the cursor. "cannon" is the line. When I try to use it, the line does indeed follow the cursor, but it's got a large offset and is inverted. I'm not really sure what's wrong with it, but it's probably very obvious.

```
Dim angle as Double = Math.Atan(Math.Abs(Cursor.Position.Y - cannon.Y1) / Math.Abs(Cursor.Position.X - cannon.X1))

Dim h As Double = Math.Sqrt((Math.Abs(Cursor.Position.X - cannon.X1) ^ 2) + Math.Abs(Cursor.Position.Y - cannon.Y1) ^ 2)
Dim a As Double = h * Math.Cos(angle)
Dim o As Double = h * Math.Sin(angle)

cannon.X2 = cannon.X1 + a
cannon.Y2 = cannon.Y1 - o
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Cursor.Position gives the mouse coordinate relative to the top left corner of your monitor - as does MousePosition.Try this..

PointToClient is a function that calculates the position of the mouse relative to your program window.

```
Dim angle as Double = Math.Atan(Math.Abs(Me.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y - cannon.Y1) / Math.Abs(Me.PointToClient(MousePosition).X- cannon.X1))

Dim h As Double = Math.Sqrt((Math.Abs(Me.PointToClient(MousePosition).X - cannon.X1) ^ 2) + Math.Abs(Me.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y - cannon.Y1) ^ 2)
Dim a As Double = h * Math.Cos(angle)
Dim o As Double = h * Math.Sin(angle)

cannon.X2 = cannon.X1 + a
cannon.Y2 = cannon.Y1 - o
```